# Can positivity of currents implies positivity of forms?

Tags: complex-geometry, geometric-measure-theory, several-complex-variables

Let $\alpha$ and $\beta$  be 2 continuous (or smooth) forms of $(1,1)$-type on a complex manifold $X$. Of course they can be considered as currents. Assume $\alpha\geq \beta$ in the sense of currents.

My ques: **can we deduce that $\alpha\geq \beta$ in the sense of differential forms?**